# JavaFX translateZ for a non-root node causes it to disappear

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I'm trying to use the translateZ property on a VBox to move the panel "into the screen".

If I use setTranslateZ() on the root node this works fine. However if I change root.setTranslateZ(200); to panel.setTranslateZ(200); the window is blank.

```
public class Demo01HelloWorld3D extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Button button = new Button("Press me");

        VBox panel = new VBox(button);
        panel.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        panel.setDepthTest(DepthTest.ENABLE);

        VBox root = new VBox(panel);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.setDepthTest(DepthTest.ENABLE);
        root.setTranslateZ(200);
        // panel.setTranslateZ(200);  <== I want this to work

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 320, 240, true);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        scene.setCamera(new PerspectiveCamera(false));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```

Setting translateZ on the root node

[image: translating the root node work as expected]

Setting translateZ on the panel node

[image: settings the panel node causes the screen to be blank]

Things I've tried

- Setting depthTest attribute to enable - although I don't think this is necessary as it defaults to DepthTest.INHERIT
- Lots of searching for similar questions!
- Checking SCENE3D is enabled - yes it is
- Checking the javadoc for [translateZProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#translateZProperty())
- checked Z value is less than camera clippingFar property
- Looked at [Oracle JavaFX 3D](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/8/3d_graphics/sampleapp.htm) tutorial - this does not specifically address 3D with standard controls and containers etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `panel.setTranslateZ(200);` you're pushing the `panel` behind the `root`, so the `root` obscures it.

Add `root.setStyle("-fx-background-color: transparent;");` and it works:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    Button button = new Button("Press me");

    VBox panel = new VBox(button);
    panel.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    panel.setDepthTest(DepthTest.ENABLE);

    VBox root = new VBox(panel);
    root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    root.setDepthTest(DepthTest.ENABLE);
    root.setStyle("-fx-background-color: transparent;");

    panel.setTranslateZ(200);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 320, 240, true);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    scene.setCamera(new PerspectiveCamera(false));
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I just found it too, although I used setBackground(null);